# ApexCharts: change the default blue color of the zoom/pan icons

Tags: reactjs, apexcharts

How can I change the default blue color of the zoom/pan icons in the top right of the chart? https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ob2Jf.png

Comment: From the documentation. it looks like you have to provide images to customise the toolbar icons. https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/chart/toolbar/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change it with CSS

```
.apexcharts-zoom-icon.apexcharts-selected svg {
  fill: #68e397 !important;
}

.apexcharts-pan-icon.apexcharts-selected svg {
  stroke: #68e397 !important;
}
```